# How insert a line in a sorted file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I generate a lot of string with a loop and I need to write these string in a file. I want that my file are sorted. The following code illustrates what I want to do:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
my_file = open('my_file.txt', 'w')

#randon_string and insert_in_order_alphabetically are just for the example
for x in range(1,100000000):
    my_string = random_string()
    my_file.insert_in_alphabetical_order(my_string)

my_file.close()
```

Does Python have functions for do this or Do I need to code my own algorithm?

Comment: is it necessary to _enter_ them alphabetically -- you could just `sort()` after you have compiled all strings e.g. in a list?

Comment: If you insert something into a file you have to move all content afterwards to a new position. With the large number of iteration that would take `string_length * 100000000/2 * 100000000` bytes to be rewritten on average. So, you have to do the sorting in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The smartest thing to do would be to read the file in as a `list`, add all the extra strings and then use `sort` on the list, before rewriting to file.

E.g. given the file:

```
c
c
c
a
a
b
a
a
```

And the code:

```
lines = []

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

lines.append('z')
lines.append('e')
lines.append('e')

lines.sort()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

This creates the file:

```
a
a
a
a
b
c
c
c
e
e
z
```

Comment: The problem is my size file do > 100Go and I want to avoid to split my file and sort and merge the splits. I think I just will write my own algorithm.